# Trying to create a SharePoint online (office 365) dashboard with doc list web parts and display based upon login

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, security, dashboard

I have a a SharePoint Online (office 365 web site).   Under a team site,  I have created 3 document libraries (one for each person A, B, C).    I have removed all   permissions for each document library so only each person can read and edit their own library.  In addition, I added one EXTRA permission so person D can read all and edit all 3 doc libraries A,B and C.  That all works perfectly when logging in as each user and going directly to  the libraries.

Here is my problem.    I created one  web part page as a "dashboard"  and dropped document Web parts with each document library for A, B and C.   When person D logs in, they see all the lists.  But when person A logs in, they do see theirs but also they see "Error Access Denied" on the other web parts on the page.  In quick launch menu - they see only their document lib listed.  But the other web parts are shown with the error I just described.

There must be a simple way to create a dashboard page of web parts that show only those each person is allowed to see.   Please ... any links to any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AmitKB is right with Audience Targeting, but that's like using a bazooka to hunt a rabbit.

Alternatively, if you only want to *display* on the dashboard/landing page, insert a Content Search Web Part.

Customize your query like this:

```
ContentClass=STS_ListItem AND
    (path:https://URL/site/listA OR
     path:https://URL/site/listB OR
     path:https://URL/site/listC)
```

Or any other selection you choose, it may be easier to specify the site, listID or whatnot depending on your setup.

Select the option "Don't show anything when there are no results".

You can customize what happens when you click. But by default clicking an item will take you to the document page. A+D will be able to maintain items from the A list here, B+D on B list, and C+D on C list.

The downside to this approach is that users will need to go to the individual libraries to add new content. You cannot add a document using a search web part.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Audience Target](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-a-Web-Part-to-a-specific-audience-d4076339-dc25-48be-9a2b-ffafdf33e9d8) option can help you.

If you properly setup it, the WebPart will hidden if not applies to user and eliminates showing error thrown by WebPart.

You may also check this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pu33PiA1vFY).

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought that was the way to go but I thought nahhh... There has   got to be something better right?  Lol.